# Get content between shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the content between a wordpress shortcode.

Like say `[bla_blabla name="a"]Variation A[/bla_blabla]`

should return `Variation A`

I thought of using regex to get it, but there is a `shortcodes.php` file in wordpress which should already be capable of doing it? Could you guide me into the correct way  of doing it?

I have currently used this code

```
<?php
function abtest_runner($input) {
    //A bit confused if you wanted equal chances of selecting one or equal changes?
    //This is for equal chances.
    $size = count($input);
    $select = rand(0,$size-1);
    $temp=array();
    $selection = $input[$select];
    $temp = (explode("]",$selection));
    $temp = (explode("[",$temp[1]));
    echo $temp[0];

}

$input[0] = '[bla_blabla name="a"]Variation A[/bla_blabla]';
$input[1] = '[bla_blabla name="b"]Variation B [/bla_blabla]';

abtest_runner($input);
?>
```

Comment: What you are tring to achieve? may be there is a simpler way for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have registered you shortcode in WordPress using the `[add_shortcode][1]` function then, you can extract your shortcode content using the following method:

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
$content  = '[bla_blabla name="a"]Variation A[/bla_blabla]';
$matches = array();
preg_match("/$pattern/s", $content, $matches); 
print_r($matches[5]);
```

`$matches[5]` will contain your content.

Hope this helps.